# Avoid making the same assertions on data in SQL Language as you do in your domain

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, scala, eventual-consistency

Imagine that The `class Purchasable` looked like this in `scala`

```scala
case class Purchasable(product: ProductData,store: StoreData,seller: UserData){
  require {
    //seller is active &&
    //seller has defined personal info &&
    //seller has defined means of accepting payment
    //product contains a price in seller's current currency
    //product has defined shipping policies for atleast on of the store's locations
    //product is not past expiration date
    //product is either new or has uploaded images
    //and so on!
  }
}

object Purchasable {
  def validate(p: ProductData,s: StoreData,u: UserData): Either[String,Purchasable] = {
    Try(Purchasable(p,s,u)).toOption.toRight("unpurchasable.product")
  }
}
```

types `ProductData`, `StoreData`,`UserData` all reperesent rows from 3 database tables.

a successful `Purchasable` instance must be obtainable from these three fetched rows when a buyer wants to buy a product or add it to her cart.

But naturally before the buyer adds this item to her cart, she'd have to first query our database for a list of **purchasable** products.

It's obvious that querying for these purchasables makes for a very complex condiotinal clauses in SQL (which isn't my major concern). My main concern is the duplicated logic that has to be written in **two** entirely different languages So what I thought of doing was create another table called `purchasables` which holds all product ids that pass the purchasable criteria; I stream the three rows from db, validate them each with `Purchasable.validate` in scala and insert them into the new table. so now I have two benefits:

- my query becomes as simple as:

```sql
select * from products p 
join stores s on p.storeId = s.id 
join users u on s.userId = u.id
join purchasables pur on pur.productId = p.id
```

- No duplication of logic and maintainability issues. If business requirements change I only need to change one place in code.

The downside I see is that my purchasable products now have what they call **Eventual consistency** instead of immediate. since the `purchasables` table gets refreshed only periodically, even if it was every 2 minutes.

My question: Is what I've done here an established practice? I searched for it on the internet and all talks and techniques regarding eventual consistency is addressed towards distributed systems issues. I haven't found a single article or stackoverflow question about discussing the choice. It's in situations like these that I feel like I'm totally off track and without a single clue as to what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed something, but I think your first approach was simpler and on track.

You say you need to duplicate logic in two languages, but I don't see why that would be.

For what I understand, validating that a product is purchasable, and finding all purchasables ones is actually the same thing. It's `find all purchasables in this source table`, source table which may be as small as a single element table, or as large as the full items table. So you should have a single function for it, and the same code will handle both use cases.

E.g, if you use slick, you may have a function like

```
def findPurchasablesIn(table: Query[ProductTable, ProductRow, Seq])
```

and call it with different source tables ?

Comment: I'm following a design by types philosophy. if it's purchasable there must be a type such as ```Purchasable``` that represents it and other modules depend on it.I see that your approach is a sql only verification. But sql doesn't provide explanation as to why the query didn't return a result. was it not found? or was it found but disqualified? if disqualified where exactly? also sql doesn't bring any static proof that the result qualifies for something. e.g if I ask slick to give me users with defined email addresses it would still return me an ```Option[String]``` for the email value.

Comment: are my concerns validated? I feel like addressing these concerns takes higher priority